# what's the correct way to update component after api calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose i have this component that will fetch all data from API periodically.

// on parent component

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    datas: [],
  }
  this.apiCall = this.apiCall.bind.this
}

apiCall(){
  //fetch data here
  this.setState({
    datas: //result from fetch
  })
}

ComponentDidMount(){
  this.interval = setInterval(() => this.apiCall(), 10000);
}

handleEditData(){
  //api call, edit one data in server using POST
}

...
<ChildComponent onEdit={this.handleEdit}/>
```

What should i do when child component edit data? or what should i put in handleEditData?

1. Should i edit one data by sending POST to api, and then update local state manually by using setState inside handleEdit?
2. Or should i sending POST to api, and then call apiCall function to get new datas, those  change its state and re-render?

thanks

Comment: Totally depends upon what you are getting back from your post. If you get updated data in response, then you can set state with that response. Ideally you should do this in success of post request to make sure your data has been actually updated on server.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question and it is less a question that is regarding react, and more of a resource management question. The question to ask is what the data is doing. If you have data that needs to be logged, you should store your data using the API. If the data is going to be reused in your app and you already have it, why not use it in situ? It reduces your calls (and therefore makes the app more efficient) and it creates one less point of breakage in the process.

To reiterate: When you design a system, you should look locally before you involve more moving parts. I would simply bubble up the data and use setState with the local object.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the client network connection would be lost and if you updated the data in the client side either before sending the request or after receiving the failure response from the server since that's not be updated in the back-end!!! and after refresh the browser, the consumer will see the data that have not been updated.

So I suggest you, update the data after receiving the successful response from the server.

Answer (score -1):

First you should call api for edit one data in server using POST and on the success of this api's response you can set state